# .NET Core MVC Unable to Redirect to Identity Login Page

Tags: asp.net-core, redirect, identity

I have a .NET Core MVC Application ,and i used scaffolding for Identity Pages like Login ,Logout,Register in my application .I have put a URL link in my _LayOut.csHtml file to login pages as below

```
<li><a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a></li>
```

but it doesnt redirect to Login Page .I dont think the Identity pages are MVC as there is a .cs file with each razor page,so i didnt create controller for them and return View as for other pages.

Comment: The link is correct, check the `_LoginPartial` file and make sure there is no logged in user :)

Comment: Hi,I didnt register any user or logged in with any credentials till now ,then the part of code where it checks if it is logged in user will always be false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue ,since Identity pages are Razor Pages with code behind we need to add following lines in our StartUp.cs
1)In ConfigureServices method add this line

```
services.AddRazorPages();
```

2) In Configure method add this line

```
endpoints.MapRazorPages();
```

so it will be like this

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
```

Comment: This is what helped me. My Startup.cs page did not have the "RazorPages" code because I'm using MVC Core 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

After using the Scaffold for Identity pages, please follow the instruction in [Migrations, UseAuthentication, and layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#efm) to perform the following steps:

- Create a migration and update the database.
- Add `UseAuthentication` to `Startup.Configure` file.
- Add `<partial name="_LoginPartial" />` to the layout file.
- Test the app:
  Register a user or Navigate to Login page.

More detail information about using Identity in Asp.net core, check the following links:

[Scaffold Identity in ASP.NET Core projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

[Add, download, and delete custom user data to Identity in an ASP.NET Core project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/add-user-data?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)